# In MVC how to debug what the database doesn't like when it breaks on db.SaveChanges();

Tags: debugging, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, save, edmx

I've always wondering about this as from time to time I've encountered it with no clear indication where the problem lies.

Typically I've solved this by a process of elimination but I was hoping someone could help me with a better way which I could ideally use to provide clearer/more precise error handling?

Any help would be much appreciated.

thx.

p.s. in case it helps I'm developing in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use sql server profiler for figuring out issues with edmx queries.

And for finding out select queries being generated for linq-to-entity, like in following case,

```
var linqquery = from s in db.Employees 
                where s.name = "john"
                select s;
```

you can use

```
string logQuery = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)linqquery).ToTraceString();
```

**EDIT**

Dont know anything that MVC provides for EF logging. Even EF does not have a logging built in! (LINQ-to-SQL has a Log property). Found these links which allows you to add logging to EF.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx

or

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2010/12/08/Logging-all-SQL-statements-done-by-Entity-Framework.aspx

Comment: I was looking for a solution in MVC so in visual studio rather than an external solution and specifically for edmx's as I've only used these and not linq.

Comment: Just been doing some additional checks into seeing if I could even use sql server profiler but it seems I have a restricted version/ restricted access to my sql server management studio as it doesn't even have an option for it. This backs up my question of wondering if there was anything programmatically in MVC which I could use/do to find the requested infomation out?

Comment: Although the edit doesn't provide me the ideal solution for this is does seem to lead into a possible solution and explains why I haven't seen/heard/found anything about his before, that being because entity FW doesn't have logging like linq. So for now I've +1 this answer and by friday if nothing better is suggested I'll mark this as correct.